# Not able to run create sql command with mysqli_query php

Tags: php

I have below code I am trying to run..Connection is successfully created but still mysqli_query does not create a table.What I am missing...

here is the [script](http://imguse.com/work/wordpress/wordpress/dbsetup.php) I am executing...

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxxx","xxxxx","xxx");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Successful database connection";
    }
    $tbl_users = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                  lastname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                  password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                  gender ENUM('m','f') NULL,
                  state VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                  country VARCHAR(255) NULL,
                  userlevel ENUM('admin','user') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
                  ip VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                  signup DATETIME NOT NULL,
                  lastlogin DATETIME NOT NULL,
                  activated ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                  PRIMARY KEY (email)
                 )";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $tbl_users);
    if ($query === TRUE) {
        echo "<h3>user table created OK :) </h3>"; 
    } else {
        echo "<h3>user table NOT created :( </h3>"; 
    }
```

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Comment: Instead of `table NOT created`, check the actual error `echo mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: Id column AUTO_INCREMENT needs to be Primary Key,you have email as Primary Key

Comment: It's important to always test and debug queries isolated in a proper MySQL client application, rather than in context of your PHP code.  This has an error that would have been immediately apparent if you ran it in MySQL Workbench, PHPMyAdmin, or the `mysql` command line client.

Comment: Yes Michael you are right on that.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your Primary key to the auto_increment column, remove it from email, you can set this (email) to unique if it should be

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                  id INT(11) NOT NULL // >>> PRIMARY KEY //<<< AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Err] 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

PRIMARY KEY (email) is the issue. Make id your primary key.